# After react-native upgrade, iOS bundle fails

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I recently updated to react-native 0.61.5 from 0.59.4, but now I'm getting this error:

*bundling failed: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null*

**package.json:** https://gist.github.com/projuljustin/cd2a59f905e02d10630f2a802e9665f9

**babel.config.js:** `module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};`

I've gone through https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.4&to=0.61.5 and fixed everything.

Running the app worked before the react-native upgrade.

I saw similar posts that mentioned the issue was caused by babel-preset-react-native, but I've since taken that out. Other posts mentioned updating babel-preset-react-native to version 5, but it looks like babel-preset-react-native was replaced by metro-react-native-babel-preset. I can't find anything pointing to why this wouldn't work.

I've checked all my dependencies, tried cleaning the project and re-installing node_modules and Pods, but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: any reason for not following the strict `react` version as described in the upgrade-helper tool?

Comment: I also tried 16.9.0, but I still get the error

Comment: This is my other package.json I tried based off of upgrade-helper https://gist.github.com/projuljustin/b3f2c732e1e027147f6db1a6c4240d23